# PHP form for download of multiple files with error in Safari: Failed to load resource: Frame load interrupted

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a small wordpress plugin, that allows adding downloads to products. And on the product page you have the possibility to select multiple files and download them as a zip file.

That works as it should in Chrome and Firefox, however in Safari I get the following error message and the download gets interrupted:

> Failed to load resource: Frame load interrupted.

My form looks like this:

```
<form name="download-product-files" action="/download-product-files/download-files.php" method="post" download>

// foreach loop through files as input checkboxes

<input type="submit" id="submit-download-product-files" name="createzip" value="Ausgewählte Dateien herunterladen">
</form>
```

And my donwload-files.php file looks like that:

```
if(!isset($_POST['files']) || !isset($_POST['createzip']) || !extension_loaded('zip')) {
    exit;
}
require_once("../../../../../../wp-load.php");

$file_paths = array();

// Check if Current Website URL is in files string -> yes: get file path
foreach ($_POST['files'] as $file_url) {

    if ( strpos($file_url, get_site_url()) !== false) {
        array_push($file_paths, str_replace(get_site_url(), get_home_path(), $file_url));
    }
}


if (empty($file_paths) || (!isset($file_paths) && count($file_paths) < 1)) {
    exit;
}

ob_start();

$error = ""; //error holder

// Checking files are selected
$zip = new ZipArchive(); // Load zip library 
$zip_name = 'tempLED-' . time() . '.zip'; // Zip name

# create a temp file & open it
$tmp_file = tempnam(wp_upload_dir()['basedir'] . '/download-product-files/', '');
$zip->open($tmp_file, ZipArchive::CREATE);

if( !$zip->open($tmp_file, ZipArchive::CREATE) ) { 
    // Opening zip file to load files
    $error .= "* Sorry ZIP creation failed at this time";
    return;
}

# loop through each file
foreach ($file_paths as $file) {
    # download file
    //$download_file = file_get_contents($file);

    #add it to the zip
    //$zip->addFromString(basename($file), $file);
    $zip->addFile($file, basename($file));
}

$zip->close();
ob_clean();

if(file_exists($tmp_file)) {
    // push to download the zip
    //header('Content-Type: application/zip');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($tmp_file));
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="tempLED-Produktdaten.zip"');
    header('Pragma: no-cache'); 
    header("Expires: 0");
    readfile($tmp_file);
    
    // remove zip file is exists in temp path
    unlink($tmp_file);
}
ob_flush();
```

I tried opening the form in a new tab () but also did not help...

Any ideas how I could solve that problem?

Comment: Does anything change, if you remove the Pragma and Expires headers?

Comment: No, the same error still occures

Comment: I am finding some references to Safari having these kind of problems, but that is mostly older stuff, from 2013, https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/issues/215. or 2010, https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=46491 Not sure if the scenarios described in there (combination of `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` and `Content-Disposition: attachment`; time passing between the user triggering the action, and getting a server response) are still unresolved though.

Comment: Thank you! I found those aswell, however did not find a way to solve that problem.

Is there another way I could download the files? I can get an array of the file URLs (in JS oder PHP). 
If I can not download as ZIP, but individual files it's also not a problem...

Comment: You can not download multiple files with a single request, an archive format like ZIP is pretty much the only option for something like this. Does it work if you create a permanent file on disk, and then redirect to the location of that at the end?

Comment: That more or less solved my problem.
I create the file now with the .zip extension and when created I redirect with header( 'Location: ' . path2url($tmp_file) ) ; to the file and the download starts as expected.

And I created a cron job, that deletes all the files in my temporary folder once a day

thank you.